# A function in $\Bbb{Q}$ that is not bounded but is bounded in $\Bbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis

I can not find an example of when a function is bounded in $\Bbb{R}$ but not in $\Bbb{Q}$. Can anybody help me?
$f$ is defined as $f:\{x \in \Bbb{Q}| a \leq x \leq b\} \to \Bbb{Q}.$

Comment: "a function is bounded in $\mathbb{R}$ but not in $\mathbb{Q}$" : what does it mean ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $A \subseteq B$ and $f: B \to \mathbb{R}$ a function. If $f$ is unbounded on $A$, then also on $B$. Hence, no such function exists (if I interpret the question correctly, otherwise let me know).